# Cannot Break Link in Excel - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am coping one worksheet from all the workbooks in a folder and pasting it to a new workbook called workbook2. Issue I am facing is, the VBA code I am using is not performing Data->Edit Links->Break Link action.
Because of this, workbook2 throws the warning, "This workbook contains links to one or more external sources that could be unsafe." every time the workbook2 is opened.

After copy pasting all the worksheets, the code I am using to break link before saving and closing the workbook2 is,

```
On Error Resume Next
            ExternalLinks = workbook2 .LinkSources(Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)
            If IsArray(ExternalLinks) Then
                For breaklink = LBound(ExternalLinks) To UBound(ExternalLinks)
                    wb1.breaklink Name:=ExternalLinks(breaklink), Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
                Next breaklink
            End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: Whether or not it may have any effect. But you shouldn't use variable names that are the names of functions (breaklink). Can cause you conflicts.

Comment: @Simon, i tried changing the variable name before, faced the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the next adapted code. It should send a message when a specific link cannot be removed:

```
Sub testBreakLinks()
 Dim ExternalLinks, brLink As Long, WB1 As Workbook

  Set WB1 = ThisWorkbook 'use here your workbook to be processed
 
    ExternalLinks = WB1.LinkSources(Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)
    If IsArray(ExternalLinks) Then
        For brLink = LBound(ExternalLinks) To UBound(ExternalLinks)
                On Error Resume Next
                WB1.BreakLink name:=ExternalLinks(brLink), Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
                If err.Number <> 0 Then
                    MsgBox err.Description & " - " & ExternalLinks(brLink)
                    err.Clear: On Error GoTo 0
                End If                
        Next brLink
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
End Sub
```

It will work, except the cases of **protected sheets** where the external links cannot be broken and an error is not raised, neither...

**Edited**:

I created a procedure and a function able to return addresses of all cells containing such links and a list of protected sheets, **where the external links cannot be found/broken**:

```
Sub testFindLinkCellAddresses()
   Dim arrLnk, ExternalLinks, lnk As Variant, wb As Workbook
   
   Set wb = ThisWorkbook
   ExternalLinks = wb.LinkSources(Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)
   
   For Each lnk In ExternalLinks
        arrLnk = ExtLinkCells(CStr(lnk), wb)
        If arrLnk(0)(0) <> "" Then
             Debug.Print "External links for " & lnk & " exist in cells:" & vbCrLf & Join(arrLnk(0), "|")
             Debug.Print "____________________________"
        Else
             Debug.Print "No external links found for " & lnk & vbCrLf & _
                              IIf(arrLnk(1)(0) <> "", "But the next sheets are protected:" & vbCrLf & _
                              Join(arrLnk(1), ", ") & ", " & vbCrLf & " and links cannot be found/broken even if they exist there!", "")
            Debug.Print "____________________________"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
Function ExtLinkCells(strLnk As String, wb As Workbook) As Variant
    Dim sh As Worksheet, rngForm As Range, strName As String
    Dim arr, arrPr, k As Long, p As Long, cel As Range
    
    strName = Right(strLnk, Len(strLnk) - InStrRev(strLnk, "\"))
    strName = "[" & strName & "]"
    
    ReDim arr(1000)
    ReDim arrPr(wb.Sheets.count)
    For Each sh In wb.Sheets
        If sh.ProtectContents Then arrPr(p) = sh.name: p = p + 1
        On Error Resume Next
          Set rngForm = sh.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If Not rngForm Is Nothing Then
            For Each cel In rngForm.cells
                If InStr(cel.Formula, strName) > 0 Then
                    arr(k) = Split(cel.Address(external:=True), "]")(1): k = k + 1
                End If
            Next
        End If
    Next
    
    If k > 0 Then ReDim Preserve arr(k - 1) Else ReDim arr(0)
    If p > 0 Then ReDim Preserve arrPr(p - 1) Else ReDim arrPr(0)
    
    ExtLinkCells = Array(arr, arrPr)
End Function
```

The code can be improved, of course. For instance, the array keeping the protected sheets array should be declared as `Private` on top of the module and skip their processing part if the array is not empty. Showing the array content only once, at the end, if the case... But I do not need such a code. I just tried putting myself in the OP's skin and finding a way to better clarify the issue. Knowing the password, the protected sheets can be previously unprotected and protected again at the end (in code, of course) in the sequence trying to break them...